# Is it possible to use simple react-native-renderer+angular to create hybrid mobile applications?

Tags: angularjs, angular, react-native

For my company, I'm attempting to determine which of many mobile hybrid technologies we want to use going forward. If it matters, typically between 1 and 4 developers work on each project. We currently have about 10 mobile applications, and we plan to expand on many more.

Currently, we use Sencha/Ext for our "front end". We package with Cordova/PhoneGap to iPhone and android phones, with a MobileFirst back end to handle sessions, and auto-updates.

We'd like to replace at least the cordova and sencha part of our technology stack.

My question: Is it possible or even wise to use simple angular with react-native-renderer to create hybrid mobile applications?

Or, is it better to use a framework either separate from angular (e.g.: React Native) or in addition/built on to angular (e.g.: Ionic)?

My feeling is that using react-native-renderer with simple angular code will not provide us with many helpful features that the other platforms use. But I'd like to get insight from the stackoverflow community on this.

Thanks.

Comment: You really shouldn't mix Angular with React. What's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is **yes** - it is completely possible using the renderer you mentioned to utilize both features of both React Native and Angular to ship a hybrid technology. You are basically getting  a React Native application in which an Angular 2 application runs in the JS thread with a custom renderer that uses the JS APIs to create a native UI.

But is it wise or a stable long term solution? The answer to that question is definitely **no**! This is essentially gluing two different technologies together which are both in developmental stages and will present plenty of bugs and difficulty in completing and publishing your apps unless you and your developers are very fluent in both angular and react native. Almost always it is better to stick to another framework entirely and in the future possibly integrate angular again.

*Side note - run from Cordova/PhoneGap - it is not the smartest choice for any stability or consistency in development. User experience is also a downfall plus there is also serious doubt in how much longer it will be updated and maintained*